# ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for MenuController in Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am trying to add a resolver file to separate the business logic and am stuck with this error.

> ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for MenuController in /home/training/Attinad_Projects/TemplateApp/me-cmf-web-template-angular/src/app/shared/components/header/menu/menuController.ts: (?).

My menuController file is :

```js
import { ResolverMenuTheme } from './interfaces/ResolverInterface';
import { MenuTransformation } from './menuTransformation';

export class MenuController{
    menuData: ResolverMenuTheme;
    resolverObject : ResolverMenuTheme;
    menuTransformationData: any;

    constructor(menuTheme: ResolverMenuTheme){
    this.menuData = menuTheme;
    }
    menuController(): ResolverMenuTheme{
        this.menuTransformationData = new MenuTransformation();
     this.resolverObject = this.menuTransformationData.transformationMenu(this.menuData);
    return this.resolverObject;
    }
}
```

My menu component file

```js
import {
  AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChildren, ViewChild, Input, Output, EventEmitter,
  Renderer2, QueryList, Inject, PLATFORM_ID, OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { MenuConfig } from './interfaces/MenuConfig';
import { ResolverMenuTheme } from './interfaces/ResolverInterface';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { MenuTheme } from './interfaces/MenuTheme.d';
import { MenuController } from './menuController';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})



export class MenuComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @Input() menuConfig: MenuConfig[];
  @Input() menuTheme: MenuTheme;
  @Input() resolverMenuTheme: ResolverMenuTheme;
  @Output() menuClicked = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  isOpen: boolean;
  @ViewChildren('menuItem') menu: QueryList<any>;
  @ViewChildren('menuText') menuText: QueryList<any>;
  @ViewChild('submenuContainer') submenuContainer: ElementRef;
  @ViewChildren('submenu') submenu: QueryList<any>;
  @ViewChildren('submenuText') submenuText: QueryList<any>;
  @ViewChild('navBar') elem;
  @ViewChildren('navBar') navBar: QueryList<any>;
  @ViewChildren('bullet') bullet: QueryList<any>;
  menuArray: MenuConfig[];
  moreMenuArray: MenuConfig[];
  innerwidth: number;
  moreMenuItem: boolean;
  resolverObject1: ResolverMenuTheme;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) public platformId: Object,private menuControlData: MenuController) {
    this.isOpen = true;
    this.moreMenuItem = false;

  }
  /**
   * @description : the theme of different parats of the menu will be set here.
   * @returns void
   */



  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      let deviceWidth: number;
      let menuCount: number;
      let displayMenuCount: number;

      // retrieve the count of menu items
      menuCount = this.menuConfig.length;

      // retrive the width of device
      deviceWidth = (window.screen.width);
      // appending class to menu to accomodate more menu items
      if (deviceWidth > 1400) {
        displayMenuCount = 5;
      } else if (deviceWidth > 1100) {
        displayMenuCount = 4;
      } else if (deviceWidth > 800) {
        displayMenuCount = 3;
      } else if (deviceWidth > 764) {
        displayMenuCount = 3;
      }

      if (displayMenuCount < menuCount) {
        this.moreMenuItem = true;
      } else {
        this.moreMenuItem = false;
      }
      this.menuArray = this.menuConfig.slice(0, displayMenuCount);
      this.moreMenuArray = this.menuConfig.slice(displayMenuCount, menuCount);
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    new  MenuController(this.menuTheme);
    this.menuTheme.menuTextColor = null;
    this.resolverObject1 = this.menuControlData.menuController();

    // console.log(this.resolverObject);
 
    this.menuText.forEach(element => {
      this.renderer.setStyle(element.nativeElement, 'color', this.resolverObject1.menuTextColor);
    });
    this.submenuText.forEach(element => {
      this.renderer.setStyle(element.nativeElement, 'color', this.resolverObject1.submenuTextColor);
    });
    if (this.submenuContainer) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.submenuContainer.nativeElement, 'background-color', this.resolverObject1.submenuBg);
    }
  }

  /**
   * @description - styling element(menu,submenu) properties(color,bgcolor etc) on mouse hover
   * @param element - ElementRef
   * @param type - string
   * @param property -string
   * @returns void
   */
  applyStyleOnMouseHover(element: ElementRef, type: string, property: string): void {
    switch (type) {
      case 'menu':
        switch (property) {
          case 'color':
            this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'color', this.resolverObject1.menuHoverTextColor);
            break;
          case 'bgcolor':
            this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'background-color', this.resolverObject1.menuHoverBg);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        break;
      case 'submenu':
        switch (property) {
          case 'color':
            this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'color', this.resolverObject1.submenuHoverTextColor);
            break;
          case 'bgcolor':
            this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'background-color', this.resolverObject1.submenuHoverBg);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        break;
      case 'bullet':
        switch (property) {
          case 'bgcolor':
            this.bullet.forEach(el => {
              this.renderer.setStyle(el.nativeElement, 'background-color', this.resolverObject1.menuHoverTextColor);
            });
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  /**
   * @description - remove styling element on mouse leave
   * @param element - ElementRef
   * @param type - string
   * @param property -string
   * @returns void
   */
  removeStyleOnMouseLeave(element: ElementRef, type: string, property: string): void {
    switch (type) {
      case 'menu':
        switch (property) {
          case 'color':
            this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'color', this.resolverObject1.menuTextColor);
            break;
          case 'bgcolor':
            this.renderer.removeStyle(element, 'background-color');
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        break;
      case 'submenu':
        switch (property) {
          case 'color':
            this.renderer.setStyle(element, 'color', this.resolverObject1.submenuTextColor);
            break;
          case 'bgcolor':
            this.renderer.removeStyle(element, 'background-color');
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        break;
      case 'bullet':
        switch (property) {
          case 'bgcolor':
            this.bullet.forEach(el => {
              this.renderer.setStyle(el.nativeElement, 'background-color', this.resolverObject1.menuTextColor);
            });
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  /**
   * @description emit event back to parent element upon click menu
   * @returns void
   */
  openSubmenuList(): void {
    this.menuClicked.emit();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to inject an `interface` as a dependency as they can't be instantiated. Hence the error. Is your `ResolverMenuTheme` an interface?

Comment: It was added post the error, I was trying out for solutions but neither worked. I have edited the file @SiddAjmera

Comment: Yes my ResolverMenuTheme is an interface,

Comment: Can you create a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue?

This error generally occurs when Angular is not sure about a Dependency that you've injected in a Component. Which in your case will be an `Interface` which is not instantiable.

Comment: There are lot of dependent modules and components , but I will copy the menu component entirely, if it would do the cause.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpynlo?embed=1&file=src/app/menu/menuTransformation.ts

Comment: the issue came at the first place when I added and removed a parameter for the constructor. and the app shows the errors during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are passing a parameter to the constructor that can't be resolved and automatically injected by angular.

So the simplest solution is to pass these parameters to a second method, like `init()` for example. In this method Angular should not try to inject anything and you should be safe to pass your parameters withous worrying about that warning.

So you could edit your `MenuController` like this:

```
import { ResolverMenuTheme } from './interfaces/ResolverInterface';
import { MenuTransformation } from './menuTransformation';

export class MenuController{
    menuData: ResolverMenuTheme;
    resolverObject : ResolverMenuTheme;
    menuTransformationData: any;

    init(menuTheme: ResolverMenuTheme){
        this.menuData = menuTheme;
    }


menuController(): ResolverMenuTheme{
        this.menuTransformationData = new MenuTransformation();
     this.resolverObject = this.menuTransformationData.transformationMenu(this.menuData);
    return this.resolverObject;
    }
}
```

Constructor now is empty, so I have removed it, and `init()` is a simple method that you must call manually.

I don't know if this approach can be useful in your app, because I don't know how do you use `MenuController`, but the important thing to understand is the reason you obtain that warning.

**EDIT FOR MENUCOMPONENT**

If you remove previous mentioned constructor, now you have only the default one available. So you must instantiate the controller withour params like this:

```
this.menuController = new MenuController();
```

then you can pass your param to the newly created method like this:

```
this.menuController.init(this.menuTheme);
```

Comment: Can you please edit the code above, as I am not sure about what you said, I think passing parameters through constructor of a class is valid.

Comment: you just have to edit the menuController file, right?

Comment: yeah, i added an example

Comment: MenuController is being called inside menuComponent like =>  new  MenuController(this.menuTheme); but it's now popping up error =>  error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Comment: Your solution worked! thanks but I editted and solved it by another means. However since your solution did solve current issue I am marking this. thank you, I will also update the solution as another answer so that someone would be useful.